# Query a stored procedure in mongodb using spring boot

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I want to query a stored procedure in mongodb. I can query it using the command line tool but facing issue while querying using java.The piece of code(last two lines) that is throwing error is :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase mdb = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb");
mdb.runCommand(new Document("$eval", "db.loadServerScripts()"));
Document doc1 = mdb.runCommand(new Document("$eval", "mysp(5)"));
```

and the error that it's throwing is `'no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: '$eval'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}`

Now I read several posts and documentation as well stating that `$eval` or `db.eval()` doesn't works for mongo version 4.2. So what should I change in my code to make it work or what should be the possible solution. I know this question has been asked several times but those solutions are obsolete , so I need help for this. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

From mongodb-4.2, the support for the eval command is deprecated now.

So I guess the only option will be to use mongodb-4.0 as of now.

Source : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/